# Jenkins Scriptler Plugin Not Found in Available Plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Weirdly I cannot find jenkins scriptler plugin.It not already installed I checked.I tried "check now " option in plugin manager to update available plugins also .It updated but still cannot find scriptler plugin in available plugins.Is the name changed .I searched several times.Couldn't find if the name is changed.Please, help.

Comment: same for me ... , really strange

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins Scriptler plugin is no longer available, due to security reasons: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin

"Distribution of This Plugin Has Been Suspended"

Comment: Thanks you very much.I don't know howi missed that.I need a proper way to use groovy scripts like scripler did.I don't see any plugin similar to it.